# How to use loop for query data sum db until empty db

Tags: sql, plsql

```
SELECT 
    locations, lotid, loadseq, startdate,
    SUM(DECODE (bintype||binnum, 'DB1', binvalues)) db1, 
    SUM(DECODE (bintype||binnum, 'DB2', binvalues)) db2 
FROM 
    test_summary_bin 
WHERE 
    lotid = 'C659300'
GROUP BY 
    locations, lotid, loadseq, startdate
ORDER BY 
    startdate
```

I have coding and I am curious about how to loop for select [sum (DECODE (bintype||binnum, 'DB1', binvalues)) db1] until entry . Because the data has DB a lot of columns.

Comment: I don't understand what "until empty db" (from the title), or "until entry" (in the question) mean. Is it "empty" or "entry" and - once we figure it out - what it actually means? Anyway: code you posted is OK. Loop means row-by-row processing and will be way slower than set-oriented statement, such as the one you currently have. So, why do you think you need a loop?

Comment: I mean until finish column 
So the main question is how to select statement each record 
I mean the locations, lotid, loadseq, startdate, can run 
So I need to find "DB1 to DB...." until finish DB column.
I thought It need loop for find statement.

Comment: I am sorry for my English

Comment: Aha, you meant to say that concatenation of BINTYPE and BINNUM columns can be e.g. DB1, DB2, DB3, ..., DB25, DB26? If so, then - from my point of view - the simplest way is to literally *type* that into the query. Dynamic SQL is another option, but it requires PL/SQL and is difficult to maintain and debug. If I were you, I'd copy/paste that "SUM" line and edit DB1, DB2, DB3, ... values.

Comment: Ya concatenation of BINTYPE and BINNUM . So I know but I don't know how many DB values! and If I do that I will copy and paste a lot of line maybe 100+. So It has another way to choose?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean cursor?

You can setup a cursor for this query, and loop through the result

```
DECLARE
  -- cursor that stores SQL query output
  CURSOR c_employees IS
    select full_name from employees;
  -- a row variable as a temporary hold during for-loop
  r_employee c_employees%rowtype;
BEGIN
  for r_employee in c_employees loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_employee.full_name);
  end loop;
```

See more on: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm

Comment: I was tried that. but still can not run select DB

Comment: Do you mean your SQL is invalid or the cursor execution? To access alias you can do r_sample.alias

Comment: I mean I was tried loop So ,I was post my syntax on web board and then you will see that line I have no idea to print out.

Comment: You have to declare a cursor with your query using the format I showed, you cannot directly loop a SQL statement.

Comment: You can use "SELECT INTO variable" if you are sure query return one row. Otherwise you need to declare a cursor variable to handle the reading process of multiple rows

Comment: Could you example for me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BEGIN
   FOR c_loop IN  (
    SELECT 
    test_summary_bin.locations , 
    test_summary_bin.lotid, 
    test_summary_bin.loadseq, 
    test_summary_bin.startdate,
    sum (DECODE (bintype||binnum, 'DB', binvalues)) db1 --This command I need to run with loop
    FROM test_summary_bin 
    WHERE lotid = 'C659300' 
    group by test_summary_bin.locations, test_summary_bin.lotid, test_summary_bin.loadseq, test_summary_bin.startdate )
    
    LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (c_loop.locations || ' ' || c_loop.lotid || ' ' 
         || c_loop.loadseq || ' ' || c_loop.startdate);
    END LOOP ;

      END ;
```

**I tried that but I have no ideal **

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBoSG.png

I need to do this table. I was post up there for my syntax.

Comment: Please, don't post additional data to your question as an answer, it's better editing your question to add all the additional information the comments are asking for. Also, instead of adding a screenshot, you can add the table data conveniently formatted, look for how to add a table using markdown syntax in StackOverflow.